# Calling a class member variable from within the same class gives a NameError in Python

Tags: python, static

I'm trying to call a class member variable from within its class, but I get a `NameError: name '...' is not defined`.

A similar situation is created by means of the following minimum working example:

```
from pprint import pprint


class MyClass:

    _my_class_variable = {'key_0': 0,
                          'key_1': 1}
    _my_keys = _my_class_variable.keys()

    pprint(_my_class_variable)  # WORKS!
    pprint([value for value in _my_class_variable.values()])  # WORKS!
    pprint([_my_class_variable[key] for key in _my_keys])  # DOES NOT WORK!
    pprint([_my_class_variable[key] for key in _my_class_variable.keys()])  # DOES NOT WORK!
```

which returns `NameError: name '_my_class_variable' is not defined`.

How is it possible that the first two `pprint` command work but not the last two `pprint` commands?

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the list comprehension is run in a separate scope (as a function, basically), except for the iterable used for the loop. So, on the lines that don't work, `_my_class_variable` is not defined.

One way to solve this would be to make sure that you pass `_my_class_variable` to an immediately executing lambda function so that it's available in the list comprehension's scope :

```
pprint((lambda _my_class_variable : [_my_class_variable[key] for key in _my_class_variable.keys()])(_my_class_variable))  # DOES WORK!
# or
pprint((lambda _my_class_variable=_my_class_variable : [_my_class_variable[key] for key in _my_class_variable.keys()])())  # DOES WORK!
```

Why does this work? List comprehensions get their own separate scope in Python 3 and are wrapped in a temporary function object and called immediately. If you were to create an explicit scope for the `_my_class_variable`, like in a function, its scope will be considered when resolving `_my_class_variable`.